# <unknown> is not a numpy array

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, numpy

i am trying to detect blue color using opencv2-python

i have written this code ::

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

    frame = cap.read()

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

 `` lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
    upper_blue=np.array([130,255,255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)

    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k ==27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\detectblue.py", line 10, in <module>
 hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array
```

please help me out by pointing where i am going wrong.
thank you.

Comment: add `print type(frame)` to check what is the type of frame. I think it's a tuple contain the captured image and some other information.

Comment: Well...i gt it correct.. jst swap "frame" with "ret,frame" in the 8th line.